# SharePoint 2013 Workflow set Date don't work with other user

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, workflow

I created a workflow.

We got a Status in the Workflow like (if Status 1 Email to xy)

One of this steps is.

```
If Status equals 5 
Set End Date to Today
then send an email to xy.
```

If User A creates the Task and set the status to 5 everything works fine. The End Date will be set right and the email goes out.

But if User A creates the Task and User B changes the Status to 5 the End Date won't be set and the Email will not be sent. The Workflow suspends.

Please help me. it drives me insane.

> RequestorId: 400118c0-0cda-967b-0000-000000000000. Details: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the workflow
>   instance. Exception details: System.ApplicationException: HTTP 401
>   {"Transfer-Encoding":["chunked"],"X-SharePointHealthScore":["0"],"SPClientServiceRequestDuration":["208"],"SPRequestGuid":["400118c0-0cda-967b-a164-0c0bb6fb7c82"],"request-id":["400118c0-0cda-967b-a164-0c0bb6fb7c82"],"X-FRAME-OPTIONS":["SAMEORIGIN"],"Cache-Control":["max-age=0,
>   private"],"Server":["Microsoft-IIS/8.0"],"WWW-Authenticate":["Negotiate","NTLM"],"X-AspNet-Version":["4.0.30319"],"X-Powered-By":["ASP.NET"],"MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices":["15.0.0.4569"],"Strict-Transport-Security":["max-age=31536000"],"X-Content-Type-Options":["nosniff"],"X-MS-InvokeApp":["1; RequireReadOnly"],"Date":["Tue, 15 Nov 2016 15:49:40 GMT"]} at
>   Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.Runtime.Subroutine.SubroutineChild.Execute(CodeActivityContext
>   context) at
>   System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance
>   instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
>   at
>   System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor
>   executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)

/edit 
I solved the Problem.
I created a spereate 2010 Workflow for the steps to set the End Date. 
Now it seems to work without Problems :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a permission issue in `Workflow History list` and `Task List` so to overcome it follow the mentioned steps below :

- Navigate to the site that the workflow is on in SharePoint 2013 Designer.
  Go to All Files -> Lists
- Right click on Workflow History
- Select Properties
- Click on Permissions for this list under the ‘Customization’ section (This should open up the edit permissions page in the browser)
- Break inheritance on this list by selecting Stop Inheriting Permissions in the new opened browser window
- Use the check box next to the appropriate group (probably the visitor's group) to select the group that needs to be updated permissions
- Select Edit User Permissions
- Grant the group ‘Contribute’ permissions
- Select OK.

Repeat the above steps for the associated workflow task list .

For more details check [SharePoint 2013 workflow cancels automatically](https://sharepointcreations.wordpress.com/2014/02/18/sharepoint-2013-workflow-cancels-automatically/)

If the issue still exists , try to review How to Elevate Workflow permissions in SharePoint 2013 as mentioned at [The Workflow was Suspended with Unauthorized HTTP / Elevate Workflow permissions in SharePoint 2013](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/01/31/unauthorized-http-workflow-how-to-create-a-workflow-with-elevated-permissions-by-using-the-sharepoint-2013-workflow/)

Comment: First of all, Thank you for your Response. But unfortunately it still doesn't work. I hope this steps will help someone else. The Thing that I don't understand is, if the creator set it to 5 it will work everytime, but if someone else (even Site Owner) set it to 5 it suspends... :(

Comment: /edit I tried to do it with a 2010 Workflow, but there it's the same Problem. But this time he fail because of wrong data Format or something like that.